# Read from excel file with square brackets in header C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to read from excel file with oleDB provider using C#:

```
                using (var fileConnection = new OleDbConnection(fileConnectionString))
                {
                    var command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select SourceName, [ExternalID] FROM [page1$]", fileConnection);
                    fileConnection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return new Source 
                        { 
//some code
                        };                
                    }
                }
```

. The only problem is that some headers in excel file have a square bracket in their name like `[ExternalID]`. Is it possible to read them? How can I do it?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try, and get exception?

Comment: I've tried. I was said that there weren't such a column in file.

Comment: You could write a loop that goes through each of the column names in your Excel sheet and prints them.  Then you'll be able to see how those columns are represented within a dataset and thus how to match the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple. Create an excel doc which contains column called [ExternalId] and try get value. If you cant get that column value, use Adapter to get whole excel, and then you can find [ExternalID] column index. The index is what you need to get values.